# AWS::S3::SignatureDoesNotMatch with aws-s3 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to upload data to amazon s3 bucket.
I am using aws-s3 gem for this purpose.
I am giving right access key and secure key but still not able to execute S3Object.store/Bucket calls, though the connection is established. They return with error "AWS::S3::SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Interestingly I am running another rails app with paperclip plugin to upload images to S3, and that is working like a charm! with same access key and secure key.

I have tried referencing some links mentioning same problem but to no luck.
[ https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=16020&tstart=0 ]

Any pointers/help/suggestions would be great. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just got this problem because I did not supply the correct region in the request.

I am using `fog` and `Carrierwave` as per the railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3) and I had to configure the region in the config/initializer for `Carrierwave`

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     '[redacted]',       # required unless using use_iam_profile
    aws_secret_access_key: '[redacted]', # required unless using use_iam_profile
    # use_iam_profile:       false,                         # optional, defaults to false
    region:                'eu-central-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    # host:                  's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    # endpoint:              'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'xxx'                                      # required
  # config.fog_public     = false                                                 # optional, defaults to true
  # config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=#{365.days.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

interestingly fog was redirected to the correct endpoint with the correct region by amazon, however, the redirected request got the failure on the authentication, maybe a problem with fog in such a situation. Fog did give a nice warning in the log

`[fog][WARNING] fog: followed redirect to calm4-files.s3.amazonaws.com, connecting to the matching region will be more performant`

but to be more accurate they should say `not only more performant, but it will actually work as well`

Answer (score 0):

Having right key and proper signing method, still experienced same errors while uploading files, with a filename full of spaces and cyrillic symbols from windows machines.